# How do I get the amount of data scanned by an Athena query using the aws-java-sdk version 1?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, groovy, amazon-athena

I'm using the aws-java-sdk version 1.11.573 to make calls to Athena to execute queries using Groovy:

```
        def queryExecutionContext = new QueryExecutionContext().withDatabase(AthenaConstants.ATHENA_DATABASE)
        def resultConfiguration = new ResultConfiguration().withOutputLocation("s3://${resultBucket}")
        def startQueryExecutionRequest = new StartQueryExecutionRequest()
            .withQueryString(query)
            .withQueryExecutionContext(queryExecutionContext)
            .withResultConfiguration(resultConfiguration)

        def startQueryExecutionResult = amazonAthena.startQueryExecution(startQueryExecutionRequest)

def queryExecutionId = startQueryExecutionResult.getQueryExecutionId()
        def queryStatusRequest = new GetQueryExecutionRequest().withQueryExecutionId(queryExecutionId)
        Awaitility.await("Athena query ${queryExecutionId}")
                  .pollInterval(new org.awaitility.Duration(pollingPeriod.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                  .atMost(timeout.toMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                  .until { hasQuerySucceeded(queryStatusRequest) }
        def getQueryResultsRequest = new GetQueryResultsRequest().withQueryExecutionId(queryExecutionId)
        GetQueryResultsResult getQueryResultsResult = amazonAthena.getQueryResults(getQueryResultsRequest)
List<Row> results = getQueryResultsResult.getResultSet().getRows()
```

And I would like to get the amount of data scanned so that I can log it as a metric so that it can be easily monitored.

I believe it is pretty straightforward to do with gversion 2, but I can't really upgrade at the moment.

Does anyone know how to get that metric?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Java V1 is not the recommended way to use the SDK. However, you can refer to this very old example here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/gov2/s3/CreateBucket/CreateBucketv2_test.go

Comment: That link gives me a 404

Comment: See the updated link]